# Django Clean_Field validation using field value from different Model

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to validate a form field in a ModelForm based on the value of another field in a different model.

Here is my ModelForm. CompanyData Model contains an "arr" field that I want to use as the value to validate against (that the "rev_goal" is higher):

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from company_data.models import CompanyData
from plans.models import Plan

class PlanCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean_rev_goal(self):
        rev_goal = self.cleaned_data['rev_goal']
        company_data = self.object.companydata = CompanyData.objects.get # This is wrong. But how do I get the arr field from CompanyData here so the next line of code works?**
        if rev_goal < company_data.arr:
            raise ValidationError("Revenue goal must be greater than current ARR $")
        return rev_goal

    class Meta:
        model = Plan
        fields = ['plan_name', 'rev_goal', 'months_to_project', 'cpl', 'conv_rate']
```

More detail was requested so here are the two models showing the relationships between the two:

```
class CompanyData(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    arr = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    num_cust = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])

class Plan(models.Model):
    companydata = models.ForeignKey(CompanyData, related_name='companydata',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)


    plan_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rev_goal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, validators=[validate_rev_goal])
    months_to_project = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    cpl = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(.01)])
    conv_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(.01)])
```

And I going about this completely wrong? Or is it possible to access the value of a field of a different model in a ModelForm? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You need to explain how CompanyData is related to Plan, and how you will determine which CompanyData you need to get.

Comment: Hi Daniel. I've added the two models being referenced. CompanyData is OneToOne to User. Plan is OneToOne to CompanyData. Please let me know if I haven't provided what you needed to understand the relationships. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Ok but this is a form where you're *creating* a Plan. So how do you know what CompanyData to use?

Comment: Hmmm...Good question. Each User can only have one CompanyData object. I make sure that this object is always created before they fill out the Plan Form and create a plan object. Not sure if I am answering but it would be the single instance of the CompanyData object attached to the same User Model.

Comment: So, you would need to pass in the current user to the form, and access its companydata attribute.

Comment: That makes sense to me. I'm not sure how to do this however. I'm guessing I import the User model then somehow reference it in my clean_ method?